# How to retrieve slopes and standard errors of the slopes of two simple linear regression lines?

Tags: r, linear-regression, standard-error

I have this data.frame:

```
 set.seed(12345)
 df <- data.frame(
      p=c(rep("A", 39), rep("B",61)),
      x=rnorm(100, 34, 20), 
      y=rnorm(100, 21, 25))
```

How can I obtain these four variables:

> **Slope** from simple linear regression line from group A (comparing x to y).

> **Slope** from simple linear regression line from group B (comparing x to y).

> **Standard error of the slope** from simple linear regression line from group A (comparing x to y).

> **Standard error of the slope** from simple linear regression line from group B (comparing x to y).

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thousands of possibilities.
You can try this for visualization:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
df %>%
  filter(p == "A") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = p)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
   ggpubr::stat_regline_equation(show.legend = F) 
   geom_abline(slope = 0.0269, intercept = 38.3)
```

[image]

And this for values:

```
library(broom)
df %>% 
  split(.$p) %>% 
  map(~lm(y~x, data = .) %>% broom::tidy(.))
$A
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)  21.2       10.1       2.11   0.0420
2 x             0.0517     0.228     0.227  0.822 

$B
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)   15.5       5.67       2.74 0.00821
2 x              0.153     0.125      1.22 0.229
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.

Comment: Are the standard errors of the slopes 0.228 and 0.125?

Comment: Its the standard error of the coefficients. Its measures the average amount that the coefficient estimates vary from the actual average value of your response variable. If you want to compare the goodness of your fits, then check R-squared instead. Change `tidy` to `glance`

Comment: I have one more question. How can I grab the values? For example if I want ```A.se``` to be 0.228 and ```B.se``` to be 0.125? Something like ```df2 <- df %>% split(.$p) %>% map(~lm(y~x, data = .) %>% broom::tidy(.))``` and then ```A.se <- unlist(temp["0"],use.names=T)[2]```? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez try `map_dbl(~slice(., 2) %>% pull(std.error))`

Comment: This is great! ¡Gracias! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(
  p=c(rep("A", 39), rep("B",61)),
  x=rnorm(100, 34, 20), 
  y=rnorm(100, 21, 25))


#fit the regression
lm_A = lm(x~y, data=df %>% filter(p == "A"))
summary(lm_A)

lm_B = lm(x~y, data=df %>% filter(p == "B"))
summary(lm_B)
```

The answer to those four questions are given in the coefficients tab of the regression summary (where 'Estimate' is the slope and 'Std. Error' is the standard error of the slope).

Comment: Thank you. Is linear model (lm) the same as simple linear regression?

Comment: You are correct. Typing lm into the help section of Rstudio will provide more details

Comment: Also note that your statement 'comparing x to y' doesn't tell you which variable is the independent variable and which variable is the dependent variable (being predicted). For this example I have assumed y is being used to predict x, if it is the other way, then flip the formula to y~x